Is there a way to get past precipitation data in OpenWeatherMap API?
Using OpenWeatherMap API (onecall 2.5), using 6 days of previous weather data in a certain area, why is there no precipitation in the JSON data?
Is there any data for this, and if there is, how do I receive it using a onecall 2.5 HTTP request?
Here's my full code:
const API_KEY = "XXX";
const LATITUDE = 26.640629;
const LONGITUDE = -81.872307;

const endDate = new Date();
const startDate = new Date(endDate.getTime() - (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

async function getWeatherData() {
  try {
    const weatherDataList = [];
    for (let date = startDate; date <= endDate; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)) {
      const weatherData = await (await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall/timemachine?lat=${LATITUDE}&lon=${LONGITUDE}&dt=${Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000)}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=imperial`)).json();

      const weatherDataLocalList = [];

      weatherDataLocalList.push(weatherData.current.temp);
      weatherDataLocalList.push(weatherData.current.humidity);
      weatherDataLocalList.push(weatherData.current.pressure * 0.02952998751);
      weatherDataLocalList.push(weatherData.current.wind_speed * 0.44704);
      weatherDataLocalList.push(1);

      weatherDataList.push(weatherDataLocalList);
    }
    predict2(weatherDataList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching weather data:", error);
  }
}

getWeatherData();

And this is the URL I'm using: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall/timemachine?lat=${LATITUDE}&lon=${LONGITUDE}&dt=${Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000)}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=imperial

"why is there no precipitation in the JSON data?" - perhaps because there wasn't any precipitation. https://openweathermap.org/api/history-api-timestamp#response: "If you do not see some of the parameters in your API response it means that these weather phenomena are just not happened for the time of measurement for the city or location chosen. Only really measured or calculated data is displayed in API response."

@CBroe so are there any other weather APIs (for free) that record all data?

The data returned by the One Call API 3.0 (for historical data) returns two sub-fields with precipitation data:

data.rain
data.snow

Each field contains an array with the precipitation rate (mm/hr) at each hour.
If these sub-fields are missing, that means there was no precipitation:

If you do not see some of the parameters in your API response it means that these weather phenomena are just not happened for the time of measurement for the city or location chosen. Only really measured or calculated data is displayed in API response.


Note this answer is for One Call API 3.0. According to this migration guide, API 2.5 had the data, but in slightly different fields: current.rain and current.snow. (API 2.5 will be shut down June 2024.)

Thanks for your answer. It does not work in One Call 2.5, only 3.0. Note that it requires a paid subscription.

The pricing page says 1000 free calls per day. @ParkingMaster

Ah, okay. I didn't see that, thanks.

Updated answer for API 2.5 using this migration guide However, 2.5 will be shut down June 2024 @ParkingMaster

I'm building a weather station in the summer that's going to serve this exact purpose, I'm only using OpenWeatherMap to test out my weather prediction model. This is perfect, thank you.
